# Bulk Load Timestamp Formatting

Tags: timestamp, etl, snowflake-task

We have a database that produces this timestamp:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

In order to load the csvs with this timestamp, is there a way to reliably do this? I have tried a number of formatting options hoping it just adds .00.00 to it and meets the criteria but no luck. Am I missing something?

I am expecting something like this maybe? As part of the copy into statement or file format?

```
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = (TYPE='CSV' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS America/Los_Angeles')
```

Table in question:

In the table in question it is like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE UsageValues (
     UsageTypeName VARCHAR(40000)  NULL, 
     UsageTotal NUMBER(38,0)  NULL, 
     etl_uuid VARCHAR(40000)  NULL, 
     etl_deviceServer VARCHAR(40000)  NULL, 
     etl_timestamp TIMESTAMP  NULL
);
```

The target column is already a timestamp. I altered it to meet the different req still get

```
'Timestamp '2020-04-09 23:01:07' is not recognized'
```

This is the session parameter as it is right now

```
TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS AUTO SESSION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue, created a simple file to load. Here's the content:

```
2020-02-20 23,Gokhan
2010-02-03 11,Test
```

I created a stage and loaded the file into the stage:

```
CREATE STAGE mystage;
put file://test.csv @mystage;
```

I created a table and run the copy command:

```
create table load_test (t1 timestamp, v1 varchar );
copy into LOAD_TEST from @mystage;
```

Because the type of the target column is timestamp, it's automatically parsed and inserted. Here's the result:

```
select * from LOAD_TEST;
+-------------------------+--------+                                            
| T1                      | V1     |
|-------------------------+--------|
| 2020-02-20 23:00:00.000 | Gokhan |
| 2010-02-03 11:00:00.000 | Test   |
+-------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Added additional comment showing the table this is going into. The timestamp column is already defined.

Comment: Please do not use any file format, just try to load as I did.